# how to make batch read a text file then display the text on the console

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a batch file that will read the contents of a text file then display all of it onto the console is this possible? also is it possible for it to search for just a key word then it will only display that line?

here is an example of the text file

```
test, C:\users\documents\picture
test1, C:\program files\
```

etc etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
C:\>ECHO test, C:\users\documents\picture >foo
C:\>ECHO test1, C:\program files\ >>foo
```

Display the entire text file:

```
C:\>TYPE foo
test, C:\users\documents\picture
test1, C:\program files\
```

Display just the line containing "test1,":

```
C:\>FINDSTR "test1," foo
test1, C:\program files\
```

---

For more information:

```
C:\>HELP TYPE
C:\>HELP FINDSTR
```

And in general:

```
C:\>HELP
```